# sql command for wordpress to remove random text from posts

Tags: mysql

i have like 80k posts in wordpress

all posts have text like that

```
<p><strong>read more: uguguf</strong></p>
<p><strong>read more: hjgjgf</strong></p>
<p><strong>read more: ihih</strong></p>
<p><strong>read more:ugff</strong></p>
```

after text "read more: random text

so only way to find this random text is search and replace for 'read more:'

i try this sql command

```
UPDATE wpw8_posts SET post_content = REGEXP_REPLACE(post_content, 'read more:".*"', '') WHERE ID = 237955;
```

to test it at post id 237955

after use sql i see only remove read more:

like that

```
<p><strong>uguguf</strong></p>
<p><strong>hjgjgf</strong></p>
<p><strong>ihih</strong></p>
<p><strong>ugff</strong></p>
```

how to remove this random text

Comment: So what do you want to happen?

Comment: that the result looks like the last table in the post @Eric

Comment: You don't need a regexp. Just `REPLACE(post_content, 'read more:', '')`

Comment: Your regexp shouldn't even match. It has `"` around `.*` but that doesn't appear in the content.

Comment: @Barmar he has sometomes spaces behind the read me:

Comment: @nbk I don't think spaces at the beginning of a `<p>` are significant, so it's OK to leave them.

Comment: @Barmar his endreslt has no spaces before the random text, so it maters

Comment: @nbk He probably doesn't realize that it doesn't matter.

Comment: i want remove full like so after read more is random text

Comment: @Eric problem is not space problem is text after "read more:"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you only want to remove read more: wuth or without a space you can use `'<strong>(read more:)([[:space:]]*)'` as pattern

```
CREATE TABLE wpw8_posts
    (`post_content` varchar(41))
;
    
INSERT INTO wpw8_posts
    (`post_content`)
VALUES
    ('<p><strong>read more: uguguf</strong></p>'),
    ('<p><strong>read more: hjgjgf</strong></p>'),
    ('<p><strong>read more: ihih</strong></p>'),
    ('<p><strong>read more:ugff</strong></p>')
;
```

```
UPDATE wpw8_posts SET post_content = 
  REGEXP_REPLACE(post_content, '<strong>(read more:)([[:space:]]*)', '<strong>') ;
```

> ```
> Rows matched: 4  Changed: 4  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM wpw8_posts
```

| post_content |
| --- |
| <p><strong>uguguf</strong></p> |
| <p><strong>hjgjgf</strong></p> |
| <p><strong>ihih</strong></p> |
| <p><strong>ugff</strong></p> |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/N3izoYe6)

if you need to remove read more inclusive the random text

```
UPDATE wpw8_posts SET post_content = 
  REGEXP_REPLACE(post_content, '<strong>(read more:)(.*)</strong>', '<strong></strong>') ;
```

> ```
> Rows matched: 4  Changed: 4  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM wpw8_posts
```

| post_content |
| --- |
| <p><strong></strong></p> |
| <p><strong></strong></p> |
| <p><strong></strong></p> |
| <p><strong></strong></p> |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QHUSipcT)

or the hole thing

```
UPDATE wpw8_posts SET post_content = 
  REGEXP_REPLACE(post_content, '<p><strong>(read more:)(.*)</strong></p>', '') ;
```

> ```
> Rows matched: 4  Changed: 4  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM wpw8_posts
```

| post_content |
| --- |
|  |
|  |
|  |
|  |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XH7Ht-lM)

Comment: thank you but i want remove full line not only read more :

Comment: i don't understand what you want to delete, what do you mean by the hole line all from <p> to </p>?

Comment: if i have full line like that "read more: grhghirhi" i want delete it so problem is after read more is random text

Comment: see if the update helps, else you need to demonstrate what the endreult should be , because you have rows and columns and not lines

Comment: thank you for help i test it now and it work good

Comment: if after read more or after space how to get it like that "read more : fhvrgurh"

Comment: you can see here howit is done https://dbfiddle.uk/Pj4ETAxB maybe you should take a look at regular expressions

Comment: thank you i try it work good but if have enter between p tag and text,sorry but regular is hard for me i try like 50 time and fail for that i ask here

Comment: like you old answer space code are enter have code for it?

Comment: It takes some time to understand the logic, but you can use reg101 https://regex101.com/ to test your patterns

Comment: i try \n i don't know what code to new line

Comment: Try \r\n, but can make a fiddle and post here to see what you I am slightly confusef

Comment: i think enter is hard to replace , but after i try on same posts 0 effect this is my code (UPDATE wpw8_posts SET post_content = REGEXP_REPLACE(post_content, '<p><strong>(شاهد ايضا: )</strong>(.*)</p>', '') WHERE ID = 169254;)
to replace (<p><strong>شاهد أيضًا: </strong>ما معنى قربانة في المسيحية</p>)

Comment: Add your text as insert to the dblink , your pattern doesn't match the samples yo have given, regex needs an exact pattern that must be equal in the posts. Asong as I don't know what the data looks like , you must test your patterns in regex101

Comment: is arabic char have problem with that? test work on same and other not and i dont why this happen my data like that <p><strong>شاهد أيضًا: </strong>ما معنى قربانة في المسيحية</p>